# Take diff of two different git repositories

Tags: git

I have two seperate git repositories at ~/linux and ~/android. I want to make a diff of the two repositories using git. Or is there any way to merge the two repositories.?

Regards,
Murugaprabu

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch --all $HOME/android` in the other directory and then use `git diff` in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Add both repos as remotes, fetch them and then diff/merge/do whatever you want.